# the tab character in python really confuse me

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
i = 1
while  i <= 6:  
    print 2**i,'    ','\t', 3**i  
    i += 1
print
```

---

```
i = 1     
while  i <= 6:
    print 2**i ,'\t', 3**i
    i += 1
print
```

This is the two different code I wrote. For the first one, I add four spaces and the output is strange. If I change the four spaces into three spaces, the output of the two codes will be the same. I don't understand it.

Output:
[image]

Comment: Do *not* post pictures of code or results, *post the text in your question*.

Comment: A tab advances the cursor to the next multiple of some number, often 4 or 8. By adding 5 spaces, the next tab is different for 1- and 2-digit numbers.

Answer (score 1):

If you want fixed, formatted output you should look into formatted print statements instead of using tabs.  This site has a good description: https://pyformat.info/   The *padding and aligning* section is probably what you want to start with to help clean up your output.